# Edit custom file properties in Google Drive UI

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script

Once I was looking through Google Drive API docs and I have seen a picture of Google Drive UI and a sidebar on the right, I guess it allowed to edit custom [file properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties). I need to let the user add some data to a file (like an email), so I could get it with Java SDK later.

Is it possible to edit custom properties right in Google Drive UI or that was my fantasy? Can you point out to a guide? Perhaps, it involves Google Apps Script or something.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive UI doesn't include a built-in way for end-users to edit custom properties but they could use [Google Apps Script's Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) .

> Adding custom properties
>
> The following example demonstrates how to add a custom property to a
>   file. Unlike Apps Script's [document properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties), Drive's custom file
>   properties can be accessed outside of Apps Script and by other
>   applications (if the visibility is set to `PUBLIC`).
>
> ```
> function addCustomProperty(fileId) {
>   var property = {
>     key: 'department',
>     value: 'Sales',
>     visibility: 'PUBLIC'
>   };
>   Drive.Properties.insert(property, fileId);
> }
> ```

Related:

- [Is there a way to edit/show custom properties in Google Drive in the Details tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49099385/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

I have built a UI for adding custom properties to **Google Docs** . You can checkout the extension on [chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gdoc-metadata-adder/nfndchcnoegibahignhlciiicaenoiic). I also made a walkthrough video which can be viewed on [youtube](https://youtu.be/hmIDqkMVvYc).

However, I understand google drive stores more than docs file. It also stores file like google sheet. You can view the code on [github](https://github.com/imox2/gdoc-metadata-adder). I think you can make it work with google sheet or anything else with minor modification.

Comment: The link to Chrome Store is broken.